# How to identify the type of const char* and const char[] in code?

Tags: c++, arrays, c-strings

```
const char* s1   = "teststirg";  
const char  s2[] = "teststirg";
```

I want a method tell me that s1 is "char*" and s2 is "char[]",how to write the method?

Comment: Do you want a function that takes a char* but can tell you how it was declared originally? I don't think there's a portable way to do that.

Comment: Yeap,there's not a portable way to get the originally type.Just a little trick to get the intuitive type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use templates:

```
template<typename T, unsigned int SIZE>
bool IsArray (T (&a)[SIZE]) { return true; }

template<typename T>
bool IsArray (T *p) { return false; }
```

This will evaluate at runtime.
Usage:

```
if(IsArray(s1))
...

if(IsArray(s2))
...
```

If interested, you can use some advance techniques, which will tell you this as compile time.

**Edit**:

```
typedef char (&yes)[2];

template<typename T, unsigned int SIZE>
yes IsArray (T (&a)[SIZE]);

template<typename T>
char IsArray (T *p);
```

Usage:

```
if(sizeof(IsArray(s1)) == sizeof(yes))
...
if(sizeof(IsArray(s2)) == sizeof(yes))
...
```

Comment: Isn't it very likely the first version will be inlined and const-propagated so that compile-time vs run-time ends up being the same anyway? In outputted binary that is.

Comment: @KillianDS, For this particular case you are right. But the 1st version cannot be used as part of `template` arguments as it doesn't result in compile-constant. May be with C++11 `constexpr`, we might be able to use 1st version also as compile time constant.

Comment: @KillianDS: yes, however unless marked `constexpr` the first version cannot be used for meta template programming.

Comment: when you call 'IsArray(s2)',get the compile error:'IsArray' : ambiguous call to overloaded function; could be 'bool IsArray<const char>(T *)'or 'bool IsArray<const char,4>(T (&)[4]);

Comment: @AlanGame, I checked in my compiler g++4.6, it doesn't give any error. [Check this test code](http://ideone.com/tjW48). Let me know which part it's giving error. Paste your minimal code in [ideone](http://ideone.com/).

Comment: [The Compile Error](http://ideone.com/Rokmo) Then please [Check This](http://ideone.com/VzAw5)

Comment: @AlanGame, your second link is not opening. Actually `"hello"` can be considered `const char*` and `const char [6]` both, that's why the ambiguity error. Surprisingly in my g++4.6.1, it doesn't throw compiler error. Anyways, you can change `T *p` to `const T *&p` and your [compilation would go fine](http://ideone.com/MXU16).

Comment: @AlanGame, you can use that solution also, but remember that it's again runtime and you have unnecessary specialization of `class` which is not needed IMHO. I would suggest the compile time solution (because it doesn't need any execution cycles). 2nd one is the compile time solution in my answer.

Comment: Your solution is much better. I prefer compile time solution too,ths.^-^

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the original definition, then `typeid` can be used (but what for, I don't know).  If you don't have access to the original definition...  There's no way of knowing whether a `char*` was initialized from another `char*`, or from an array.

Answer (score 0):

In the above context ( that is in the same method where we have the declaration),

```
   /*1*/ s1[0]='\0';
   /*2*/ s2=s1;
   /*3 Only This is valid*/  s1=s2;
   /*4*/  s2[0]='\0';
```

Your compiler wouldn't allow step 1,2,4 to pass, while step 3 would succeed. This clearly indicates the nature of the variables. Now, as regards the method (function call) to determine that, you will have to have the definition in the method signature anyways, so I dont see any purpose/utility/possiblity of this method.

```
determiner (const char* s1,const char *const s2)
```

You already have  the definition in the signature.You need to bypass compiler, to get a use case for this.
I apologise , If I haven't got your requirement correct.